# Виснет приложение (PyQt + socket)

Tags: python, gui, сокет, pyqt, клиент-сервер

У меня возникла проблема. Пишу чатик `socket + PyQt5`. 
До того как стал переносить сервер и клиент на *PyQt* было все шикарно и работало как надо. Но при запуске приложения на *PyQt* после любого действия виснет.

Я пробовал не использовать функцию `refresh` и все было ок. При `connect` следующие две строчки проходили как надо:

```
data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')  
self.textBrowser.append(data)
```

но при последующем запросе:

```
(self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

приложение висло.

Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю в чем кроется ошибка?

---

**server.py**

```
import socket, threading

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
print("Сервер запущен")
serverRunning = True


def handle_client(conn, uname):
    clientConnected = True
    keys = clients.keys()
    help = 'В чате есть 3 команды:\n1**chatlist > выводит список всех людей в чате ' \
           '\n2**quit > Завершает вашу сессию и отключает от чата\n3**(username) ' \
           'Отправляет приветное сообщение для username'

    while clientConnected:
        try:
            response = 'Количество пользователей\n'
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            found = False
            if '**' not in data:
                for k, v in clients.items():
                    if v != conn:
                        v.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
                        found = True
            elif '**chatlist' in data:
                clientNo = 0
                for name in keys:
                    clientNo += 1
                    response = response + str(clientNo) + '::' + name + '\n'
                conn.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
                found = True
            elif '**help' in data:
                conn.send(help.encode('utf-8'))
                found = True
            else:
                for name in keys:
                    if ('**' + name) in data:
                        data = data.replace('**' + name, '')
                        clients.get(name).send(data.encode('utf-8'))
                        found = True
                    if ('**kick ' + name) in data:
                        clients.pop(name)
                        found = True
                if not found:
                    conn.send('Вы пытаетесь отправить сообщение для несуществующего пользователя.'.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            clients.pop(uname)
            print(uname + ' Вышел из чата')
            clientConnected = False


while serverRunning:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    uname = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print('%s присоеденился' % str(uname))
    conn.send('Добро пожаловать. Напишите **help для вывода всех команд'.encode('utf-8'))
    if conn not in clients:
        clients[uname] = conn
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, uname,)).start()
```

---

**client.py**

```
import socket, threading

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
uname = input()
s.send(uname.encode('utf-8'))
clientRunning = True


def echo_data(sock):
    serverDown = False
    while clientRunning and (not serverDown):
        try:
            data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
        except:
            print('Сервер упал :( Вы отключены. Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти...')
            serverDown = True


threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args=(s,)).start()
while clientRunning:
    tempMsg = input()
    data = uname + ': ' + tempMsg
    s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

**chat.py**

```
import socket, threading
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from clientui import Ui_MainWindow


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.refresh)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.connect)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send)
        self.message = ""
        self.username = ""
        self.clientRunning = True
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 4000
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect((host, port))
        threading.Thread(target=self.refresh).start()

    def connect(self):
        self.username = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.s.send(self.username.encode('utf-8'))
        data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        self.textBrowser.append(data)

    def send(self):
        self.message = self.lineEdit.text()
        data = self.username + ': ' + self.message
        self.textBrowser.append(data)
        self.s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
        self.lineEdit.setText('')
        self.lineEdit.repaint()

    def refresh(self):
        data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        self.textBrowser.append(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**clientui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Яндекс Лицей Чат")
        MainWindow.resize(473, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 391, 411))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 530, 271, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 530, 111, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 60, 171, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 101, 20))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 101, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 12, 421, 20))
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        # self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        # self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 60, 121, 31))
        # self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 473, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ваше сообщение:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отправить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Никнейм"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Яндекс Лицей Чат"))
        # self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Группа"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Видел такой вариант. 
**Чат на Python с использованием библиотек twisted и PyQt5.**

---

**server.py**

```
from twisted.internet import reactor          # +++ pip install Twisted
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, connectionDone
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineOnlyReceiver
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MSQ Server launcher',
                                 add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("--port", action="store", dest='port',
                    help="Port to host server on.")
arguments = parser.parse_args()
arguments.port = int(arguments.port) if arguments.port else 1234


class ServerProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver):
    factory: 'Server'
    login: str = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Соединено с сервером.\nАвторизуйтесь при помощи команды /login.".encode())
        self.fillUserInput("/login ")

    def clearAll(self):
        self.sendLine("CMD: CLEAR ALL".encode())

    def fillUserInput(self, msg):
        self.sendLine(f"CMD: FILL {msg}".encode())

    def connectionLost(self, reason=connectionDone):
        # Если клиент авторизовался перед закрытием, его нужно закрыть со стороны сервера.
        if self in self.factory.clients:
            self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def lineReceived(self, line: bytes) -> None:
        """
        Вызывается при получении сервером сообщения от клиента.
        :param line: Сообщение от клиента в зашифрованном виде.
        """

        # Расшифровываем сообщение клиента
        content = line.decode()

        # Если пользователь отправил пустое сообщение, игнорируем его.
        if not content:
            return

        # Если пользователь авторизован
        if self.login is not None:
            content = f"{self.login} >> {content}"

            # Записываем сообщение в историю чата для отправки пользователям после авторизации.
            self.factory.history.append(content)

            # Отсылаем сообщение всем авторизованным пользователям в сети
            for user in self.factory.clients:
                user.sendLine(content.encode())

        # Если пользователь не авторизован
        else:
            # /login admin -> admin
            if content.startswith("/login"):

                # Пользователь ввел команду, но забыл логин
                if len(content.split()) < 2:
                    self.sendLine("Неверное использование команды. Пример использования:\n/login username".encode())
                    self.fillUserInput("/login ")
                    return

                login = content.split()[1]

                # Если введенный логин занят
                for user in self.factory.clients:
                    if user.login == login:
                        self.sendLine("Этот логин уже используется! Пожалуйста, используйте другой.".encode())
                        self.fillUserInput("/login ")
                        return

                # Если введенный логин свободен, авторизуем пользователя и шлем ему историю чата
                self.login = login
                self.factory.clients.append(self)
                self.clearAll()
                self.sendLine("Добро пожаловать, {}!\nПоследние {} сообщений:".format(self.login,
                              self.factory.history_length).encode())
                self.factory.send_history(self)

            # Если пользователь пытается слать сообщения без авторизации
            else:
                self.sendLine("Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь прежде чем слать сообщения.".encode())
                self.fillUserInput("/login ")


class Server(ServerFactory):
    protocol = ServerProtocol
    clients: list
    history: list
    history_length = 10

    def startFactory(self):
        self.clients = []
        self.history = []
        print("Server started on port {}".format(arguments.port))

    def stopFactory(self):
        print("Server closed")

    def send_history(self, client: ServerProtocol) -> None:
        """
        Отсылает последние <self.history_length> сообщений пользователю.
        :param client: Клиент, которому отправляем историю.
        """
        last_messages = self.history[-self.history_length:]

        for msg in last_messages:
            client.sendLine(msg.encode())


reactor.listenTCP(int(arguments.port), Server())
reactor.run()
```

---

**client.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from client_ui import Ui_MainWindow

from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineOnlyReceiver
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MSQ Client launcher',
                                 add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("--port", action="store", dest='port',
                    help="Port to connect to.")
parser.add_argument("--ip", action="store", dest='ip',
                    help="IP to connect to.")
arguments = parser.parse_args()
arguments.port = int(arguments.port) if arguments.port else 1234
if not arguments.ip:
    arguments.ip = "localhost"


class ConnectorProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver):
    factory: 'Connector'

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.window.protocol = self
        self.factory.window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("--- СОЕДИНЕНО С {}:{} ---".format(arguments.ip,
                                                                                             arguments.port))

    def lineReceived(self, line: bytes):
        message = line.decode()

        # Если получена команда очистки окна чата
        if message == "CMD: CLEAR ALL":
            self.factory.window.plainTextEdit.clear()
            return

        if message.startswith("CMD: FILL "):
            message = message.replace("CMD: FILL ", "")
            self.factory.window.lineEdit.setText(message)

        self.factory.window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)


class Connector(ClientFactory):
    window: 'ChatWindow'
    protocol = ConnectorProtocol

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Соединение с сервером не удалось.")

    def __init__(self, app_window):
        self.window = app_window


class ChatWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    protocol: ConnectorProtocol = None
    reactor = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("MSQ Chat")
        self.setStyleSheet(" font: 10pt Courier; QMainWindow { background-color: #aaaaaa }")
        self.init_handlers()
        self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)

    def init_handlers(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.reactor.callFromThread(self.reactor.stop)

    def send_message(self):
        if self.protocol:
            message = self.lineEdit.text()
            self.protocol.sendLine(message.encode())
            self.lineEdit.setText('')

        # Протокол не существует - подключиться к серверу не вышло.
        else:
            self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Ошибка: Нет соединения с сервером.")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event) -> None:
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return) and self.lineEdit.hasFocus():
            self.send_message()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):

        # Поле ввода всегда должно быть в фокусе.
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()
            return True
        return super(ChatWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ChatWindow()
window.show()

window.lineEdit.setFocus()

import qt5reactor                             # +++ pip install qt5reactor
qt5reactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.connectTCP(
    arguments.ip,
    arguments.port,
    Connector(window),
)
window.reactor = reactor
reactor.run()
```

---

**client_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(450, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.plainTextEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.plainTextEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit.setUndoRedoEnabled(False)
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setBackgroundVisible(False)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключение к серверу..."))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сообщение"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отправить"))
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]